# Is it possible to get the redirected URL with Mojo::UserAgent?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I know I can have `Mojo::UserAgent` redirect like this:

```
my $ua  = Mojo::UserAgent->new->max_redirects(3);
```

but is it possible to somehow get the URL it lands on after all redirects?

Comment: The docs list `$tx->redirects`

Comment: Also the URL of the most recent request in the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set your user-agent to redirect, you can get the chain of transactions with `redirects`. In each, look for the `Location` header.

Here's an example, using the Mojo Lite app I have in [3xx](https://github.com/briandfoy/3xx):

```
use v5.26;
use Mojo::UserAgent;

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;

# from https://github.com/briandfoy/3xx
# running perl app.pl daemon

foreach my $max ( 1 .. 3 ) {
    $ua->max_redirects($max);
    my $tx = $ua->get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/three');
    say "$max redirects:\n\t",
        join "\n\t",
        map { $_->result->headers->location }
        $tx->redirects->@*;
    }
```

Here's the output:

```
1 redirects:
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/two
2 redirects:
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/two
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/one
3 redirects:
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/two
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/one
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/none
```